# How can I bulk update CloudFormation stacks while keeping the parameters unchanged?

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, amazon-cloudformation

Let's say I have a number of CloudFormation stacks created from the same template. After making changes to the template, I want all stacks to be updated to the new version of the template.

I have tried doing this by creating a resource group and using Systems Manager to run an automation command, but:

1. The resource type `CloudFormation::Stack` doesn't show up in Systems Manager, which limits me to tag-based filtering
2. The tags I set in CloudFormation don't apply to stacks, they only apply to resources in those stacks.

Is there any other way to bulk update stacks? Ideally, one that allows me to automate the updates themselves.

Comment: what kind of updates you are talking about ? also have you tried the base stack/ application stack model so all the common resources used in all stacks grouped in one base stack and then cross reference it with the other application stacks  here is a useful URL
https://medium.com/@anupam.ncsu/reference-resource-from-one-cloud-formation-stack-in-another-during-formation-f5c80679f0fd

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must add the same tag for all templates of same type while creating your stacks with CloudFormation.

1) After this, just go to **Systems Manager** > **Application Management** > **Resource Groups**.

2) Choose: **Create a Resource Group**.

3) On **Group Type**, choose **Tag Based**.

4) On **Group Criteria**, under **Resource Types**, choose **AWS::CloudFormation::Stack**. Enter the tag **Key** and **Value** which you have configured your stack. In my case: **stack-type** as **Key**, and **CodePipeline-Template1** as **Value**.

5) Define your group name and save.

6) After saving your resource group. Go to **Systems Manager** > **Application Management** > **Resource Groups**. Select your recently created resource group and press **View Details**. Press **Execute Automation** and select **AWS-UpdateCloudFormationStack** option.

7) Under **Execute automation document**, choose **Rate control**.

8) Under **Targets**, for **Parameter**, choose **StackNameOrId**. For **Targets**, choose **Resource Group**. And for **Resouce Group**, enter your recently created resource group name.

9) Under **Input Parameters**, fulfill the **TemplateUrl** parameter with the URL of the template which you will update your stacks. And **LambdaAssumeRole** parameter with the role used to execute the operations on your behalf.

10) Press **Execute**.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough experience in CF. May be can help nested stacks. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html